# IE time limit for event triggering an document.execCommand('copy')?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, copy-paste

I'm using `document.execCommand('copy')` to copy the content of a `textarea`. This happens in a local .html file that is read directly from the harddrive (not via http).

To be more exact, on an `onchange` event from a `select`, I iterate over an `array`, find the correct entry, put its value into the `textarea`, then `.select()` and `document.execCommand('copy')` it.

On my computer at home, that works fine across browsers (FF, IE11). Unfortunately, on another machine, it fails to work on the Internet Explorer (same version) without any error in the console. My current suspicion is, that the other machine is simply a good deal slower than my computer at home.

Manually triggering copy on a button press seems to work fine, so I guess it's not a permission problem or similar.

So, my question is this: Is there a time limit in Internet Explorer 11 on how long a function call triggered by an event may take to still allow `document.execCommand('copy')`?

Comment: Try deferring it with a setTimeout of 0, or a defer function. There's no time limit per se, but do rememer that the javascript part of the browser isn't the same as the DOM part etc, so they are technically async to eachother. Hence you have to wait sometimes for the browser to stop javascript and resume rendering / copying for a few ms. Deferring the copy and the copy handler, will queue tthat fucntion behidn everything else that is already queued, so you have time to 'wait; for the copy to succeed. Same logic why sometimes you can't querySelector a node you just inserted.

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks the whole thing in Firefox, since Firefox only allows it in a "short running user-generated event handler", which prevents it from running in a timer (because then the event handler is already finished).

Comment: Hmm, didn't think of that. What we do, is have the execCommand resolve a promise that will make a different mediator call, so it's decoupled from the click event. But can't say if it'll work for your app. :x

Comment: I'll try adding some code that uses a timer only in IE, perhaps it helps. Will have to try different approaches, perhaps one of them works. Still guessing what's the actual problem is in any case..